# How to $unwind an embedded document (not list)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

Hi I have the following documents in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e94200cc5d957a23aa24d3a"), "items" : { "Apple" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e942013c5d957a23aa24d3b"), "items" : { "Orange" : 6 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e94201dc5d957a23aa24d3c"), "items" : { "Pear" : 3 } }
```

How do I change my above data (using $unwind or anything else better?) into the following output?

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e94200cc5d957a23aa24d3a"), "Apple" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e942013c5d957a23aa24d3b"), "Orange" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e94201dc5d957a23aa24d3c"), "Pear" : 3 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$items",
        { "_id": "$_id" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E9quXEL2BVq)

Comment: Thanks [@Ashh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/ashh)! This greatly helped! Now I know about $mergeObjects

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert your `object` into `list` with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) operator (available since `v3.4.4`)

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      items: {
        $objectToArray: "$items"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$items"              
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      items: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qof-2NiwU2g)